# C++ Dummy template parameter inducing error while using a typedef in derived template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, modularity

I'm trying to fix a weird error I'm having with this code. This is a minimal example that can replicate the error:

`test11.cpp`:

```
namespace detail{
   template <auto UInt>
   class Test{
      public:
         typedef decltype(UInt) value_type;

         Test (const value_type& x = 0);

      protected:
         value_type n;
   };

   template<auto UInt>
   Test<UInt>::Test (const value_type& x) : n(x){}

   // Here, void would be substitute with some enable_if stuff
   template <auto UInt, typename = void>
   class TestChild : public Test<UInt>{
      public:
         typedef typename Test<UInt>::value_type value_type;

         TestChild (const value_type& x = 0);
         value_type foo() const;
   };

   template<auto UInt>
   TestChild<UInt>::TestChild (const value_type& x) : Test<UInt>(x){}

   template<auto UInt>
   value_type TestChild<UInt>::foo(){
      value_type ret=42;
      return ret;
   }
}

int main(){}
```

I compiled it using GCC 7.2.0 and Clang 5.0.0 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. You can see these two links for demos:

- [gcc](https://godbolt.org/g/4X3DQr)
- [clang](https://godbolt.org/g/4dhVnR)

The error message in gcc is this one:

```
test11.cpp:27:38: error: ‘value_type’ does not name a type
    TestChild<UInt>::TestChild (const value_type& x) : Test<UInt>(x){}
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
test11.cpp:27:51: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class detail::TestChild<UInt>’
    TestChild<UInt>::TestChild (const value_type& x) : Test<UInt>(x){}
                                                   ^
test11.cpp:18:10: note: declaration of ‘class detail::TestChild<UInt>’
    class TestChild : public Test<UInt>{
          ^~~~~~~~~
test11.cpp:30:4: error: ‘value_type’ does not name a type
    value_type TestChild<UInt>::foo(){
    ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Also, the thing which is really strange for me is that, if I omit the dummy parameter in the template for the class `TestChild` (I mean, `template<auto UInt>` instead of `template<auto UInt, typename = void>`), I still get a (shorter) error that looks like this:

```
test11.cpp:30:4: error: ‘value_type’ does not name a type
    value_type TestChild<UInt>::foo(){
    ^~~~~~~~~~
```

You can check the demo for GCC 7.2.0 [here](https://godbolt.org/g/wK1JJK).

It looks like the main error is that, if I define the functions outside the class, the `typedef typename Test<UInt>::value_type value_type;` isn't really detected (I don't know if I explained myself well).

This will make sense for me if it also happens when I define the functions inside the class, but that's not the case, because everything compiles fine in the last case (you can see it in the [demo](https://godbolt.org/g/b8k8Nq) if you want to).

In conclusion, my main question is that I want to compile this program, but taking in mind that I must separate declaration from definition. So the last demo I showed (where everything is defined inside the class) is what I want to achieve, but modularizing.

I hope someone can help me and explain what is going on with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make three (at least) changes.

First: add the second (default) template value for `TestChild`.

So

```
//................vvvvvvvvvvvv
template<auto UInt, typename V>
TestChild<UInt, V>::TestChild (const value_type& x) : Test<UInt>(x){}
//............^^^
```

and the same for the `foo()` method

Second: remember that `foo()` is `const`

So

```
template <auto UInt, typename V>
value_type TestChild<UInt, V>::foo() const {
   value_type ret=42;  // ...........^^^^^
   return ret;
}
```

Third: for the return type for `foo()` explicit the class

So `typename TestChild<UInt, V>::value_type` instead of `value_type`

```
template <auto UInt, typename V>
typename TestChild<UInt, V>::value_type TestChild<UInt, V>::foo() const {
   value_type ret=42;
   return ret;
}
```

Or, if you prefer, you can use the `auto ... ->` return type syntax

```
template<auto UInt, typename V>
auto TestChild<UInt, V>::foo() const -> value_type {
   value_type ret=42;
   return ret;
}
```

or simply `auto` (but also in the declaration of the method)

```
auto foo() const;

// ...

template<auto UInt, typename V>
auto TestChild<UInt, V>::foo() const {
   value_type ret=42;
   return ret;
}
```

Comment: I forgot about the const. Anyway, I think at this point, I have many questions.  Why the scope of value_type is not needed for the constructor of `TestChild` and inside the `foo` function? Do I have to add the second template parameter in EVERY function defined outside the class? And finally, if the last is true, is there any better way to SFINAE the class without doing that much work?

Comment: @FranciscoGallegoSalido - I'm not a very expert... hoping not to write something wrong but... it's a problem of names visibility; `value_type` is defined inside `TestChild` and can be used (without explicating `TestChild`) inside but not outside the class. Defining a method of a class you are outside the class before the name of the method (`foo`), inside the class after. (continue)

Comment: @FranciscoGallegoSalido - (continue) So `typename TestChild<UInt, V>::value_type TestChild<UInt, V>::foo()` (because `value_type` is before `foo`) but `auto TestChild<UInt, V>::foo() const -> value_type` (because `value_type` is after `foo`); and so `TestChild<UInt>::TestChild (const value_type& x)` because `value_type` is after the second `TestChild`

Comment: Ok, now I get everything about the scoping of value_type (at least, it makes sense what you said), but still can't understand why I have to specify the second template parameter in every function, even if it's defaulted in the definition of the class.

Comment: @FranciscoGallegoSalido - the answer could be simply "because C++ require it"; but I see a reason: the fact that the second template parameter is defaulted doesn't change the fact that it exists; and could be used in methods. The second type parameter could be (by example) the return type of the method; if you don't specify it, what you write when (in the case) it's used?

Comment: So I see there's no option here... Well, I guess I have to change the code a little bit, if there's no other option to SFINAE the class. Thank you very much for your answer! ^.^

Comment: @FranciscoGallegoSalido - If you find annoying repeat template parameters a class names before types, a suggestion for a more compact code: define your methods inside the body of the class, not outside. After all, with template classes, I don't see great advantages in splitting declarations and definitions.